# It's ok to say "the above image" but not "the below image"

Tags: word-order

Frequently, when editing/reviewing SE posts, I see the following:

> as you can see in the below image.

Now, to me, *below image*, just sounds wrong and I reverse the order, changing it to:

> as you can see in the *image below*.

However, in my own posts, *I* will often write:

> as the above image shows

en lieu of

> as you can see in the image above

because it sounds, to me, to be a bit more in keeping with formal documentation. The phrase *... image above* is, obviously, correct also, and sounds fine, just not so technical.

#### TL;DR

- Why does *above image* sound ok, but *below image* does not?
- Am I wrong, and the only one who thinks this sounds odd?
- Why isn't the antonym of above (which is an adjective), not an adjective itself? It seems rather asymmetrical.

#### Update:

I hadn't realised that this had *already* been asked on SE ELU: [Which is correct: “the below information” or “the information below”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/which-is-correct-the-below-information-or-the-information-below). I should have checked, apologies

Comment: If 'above image' is correct, then 'below image' is correct too.

Comment: Found a good discussion on the same topic here...https://www.dailywritingtips.com/below-is-not-an-attributive-adjective/

Comment: @satnam - your excellent link contradicts your former statement... could you elaborate why you think *below image* is correct, please? You should definitely include the link, and its salient points, in an answer. I have never heard any native speaker say *below image* in 50 years, in England. Maybe it is more common in the US?

Comment: "the below image" is wrong since "below", as opposed to "above", is not an adjective.

Comment: @Cardinal - thanks... However, (and this could be another question, granted) why isn't the antonym of above (which is an adjective), not an adjective itself. It seems rather asymmetrical.

Comment: @Cardinal are you sure? See [nohat's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/which-is-correct-the-below-information-or-the-information-below)

Comment: @user178049 My reference is the dictionary(ies). e.g., http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/below 

and also this one:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/below

Comment: @Cardinal I don't agree with Cambridge either. There are more than 3k examples for `below [*n]` in COCA. Well, that is a small number; but it exists!

Comment: @user178049 - See [Ngram](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/which-is-correct-the-below-information-or-the-information-below). `[*n] below` is *way* more common.

Comment: @Greenonline I deleted my lazily wirtten answer. I hate reading it and I don't think I will have time to make it better. I hope the post on ELU is helpful.

Comment: "Below image" isn't any more wrong than "above image", but both are clunky.  They read better as "image above" and "image below".

Answer (score 1):

*The below image* and *the above image* are **writing conventions** used to refer to a figure in terms of its relative position in the text.

In the three-dimensional world of things, we say

> Noise was coming from the apartment above.
>
> You can put that book on the shelf below.

P.S. I suppose *above* and *below* would be so-called "small clauses" here.

Comment: I believe that you may have missed my point. I am not talking about spoken English, per se. As a technical writer, I would use *the above image*, but I would never use *the below image*. I *would say* it, however, if I was reviewing a technical document with a peer, face-to-face.

Comment: That's just a stylistic preference, IMO.  *The below figure* and *the below diagram* are quite well attested, even if "the below image" is not.