# Should "above" and "below" be put before or after the noun?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-order

1. Please see the above picture.
2. Please see the picture above.
3. Please see the below picture.
4. Please see the picture below.

Which are the correct positions for "above" and "below"?

Comment: Related question on EL&U [Which is correct: “the below information” or “the information below”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/609/80039)

Comment: Why is this question marked as off-topic? Another English learner with exactly the same question!

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132323/its-ok-to-say-the-above-image-but-not-the-below-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all are okay, but I think:

> Please see the picture above.
>
> Please see the picture below.

are better, but all sentences you listed are valid English sentences.

Comment: could you elaborate on why these two are "better"?

Comment: @AndrewT - I agree with this assessment, but it would be hard to explain why, other than native intuition. [This ngram is interesting and pertinent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+above+picture%2Cthe+picture+above%2Cthe+below+picture%2Cthe+picture+below&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Comment: @J.R. I do think that we can talk about how “the below picture” is using “below” as an adjective and “the picture below” is using it as a preposition (I think, but definitely not an adjective). Indian English is OK with above and below as adjectives (I think), but it’s not as widely accepted in Br or Am English.